# Can we get Altered stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi by mistake I've altered one stored procedure and is there any chance to get that old procedure?

Thank you

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (You might want to provide quite a bit more information.) :-)

Comment: I'm sure you still have the previous source version in a backup or in your source control system, don't you!?!??.....

Comment: hhmm I'm using sql server 2008. Unfortunately we are not maintaining source control for DB

Comment: **you should!** Table definitions, stored procedures etc. are source code just like your C# or VB.NET code, too! If you already have a source control system - put your database stuff under its control. If you don't have a source control system yet - **get one now!!**

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason whatsoever to not put your database in source control and treat it like any other code. You should NEVER make a change to a database without a source control script. This means never ever using the GUI to make database changes.

The only way to get back what you replaced is to restore a backup or if you have the other version on a another server, then script it and re-run on the server you you changed.

Yes fixing your source control problem is an emergency, you and your team should not write anymore code of any kind until this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Restore a backup of the affected database onto another server to get the old procedure's code, then copy just that code over.

If you don't have a spare server, you can restore the database to a different database on the same server. (create a new database, then restore the backup to that - just pay attention that you're restoring onto your new/temporary database, then delete that database when you're finished)

Red-Gate has [SQL log rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/) which might have helped (it's for SQL2000), but there might be other solutions available.